# Ads not from this site in Google Search

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

When using Google Search, there was a section of ads labelled with "Ads not from this site"

[image]

Is it normal?

Comment: What do you mean unwanted?

Comment: I mean the phrase "Ads not from this site" (and also the first example in this [page](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/unwanted) ).

Comment: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-ads-not-by-this-site/ ?

Comment: I suspect they were/are injected by some third-party add-on/extension that you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Well these Ads seem to be coming from some extensions or plugins you are using for chrome, try searching for the same keyword on some other browser to make sure that these ads are not from google (most probably they are not from google).